# Hadoop for password cracking

Tags: hadoop, password-protection

Hi I came across this [article](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/05/how-crackers-make-minced-meat-out-of-your-passwords/) and it made me wonder, how easy it would be for a hacker to crack passwords. What do you think guys???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [Recursive Algorithm on Distributed Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043347/recursive-algorithm-on-distributed-systems) an interesting way to run recursive algorithms on distributed system. Now a permutation and combination algorithms can be used to do some interesting stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out several permutations in a brute force manner, I don't think that using hadoop would give you any benefit. Hadoop is not something that fits into all uses cases and would not every time perform well.

Computing permutations can be done in batch.. just set different start and end params for each machine. The overhead involved in setting a job, movement of data across nodes, job cleanup can surely be saved. I have seen that running different processes over 5 nodes be pre-dividing the load equally performed pretty well as compared to map-reduce. Offcourse, I dont mean that map-reduce is bad.. its just that the scenario wasnt right fit for getting the job done.

Comment: We could distribute the job of computing permutations to different nodes and once we have done that, job of matching hashes can again be distributed. Also for such a large number of hashes, it could be sorted using hadoop.